# Rails Postgres. Remove indexes before loading data, then re-add them... tidily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

We have an importing process which involves loading data from XML files into the database tables of our rails app. We remove the indexes from our tables and then re-add them when loading is complete. This seems to be the recommendation (and seems to be necessary for us) to speed up the loading process. But what is a good tidy way of doing this, which avoids evil duplication? Our current approach feels... kind of clever, but at the same time horribly hacky:

We have 6 different database tables which have total of 42 different indexes defined on them. These are all defined in the Rails migrations and schema.rb, and we want to be able to make changes to these, **avoiding duplicating schema definitions elsewhere** so...

**Current approach**:

Before entering the loading logic we have this little bit of black magic:

```
indexdefs = []
import_tables.each do |table_name|
  res = @conn.exec("SELECT indexname, indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename='#{table_name}'");
  res.each do |row|
    indexdefs << row['indexdef']
    @conn.exec("DROP index #{row['indexname']}")
  end
end
logger.info "#{indexdefs.size} indexes dropped"
```

Then we load data into the tables (takes a long time), and then...

```
indexdefs.each do |indexdef|
  logger.info "Re-adding index: #{indexdef}"
  @conn.exec(indexdef)
end
```

As mentioned above, the key thing we achieve with this, is no explicit duplication of any knowledge about index definitions/schemas. We query `pg_indexes` (Postgres internal schema tables) to get details of the index definitions, as they were set-up by migrations, and then we store an array of strings, `indexdefs`, of SQL CREATE statements which we run later.

...so good and yet so bad.

What's a better way of doing this? Maybe there's frameworks/gems I should be using, or completely different approaches to the problem.

Comment: Possibly use PG_DUMP to export the indexes. There is a mailing list conversation that says you can. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/FB12A506-8A73-4A89-862B-5F0B27B14448%40gmail.com#FB12A506-8A73-4A89-862B-5F0B27B14448@gmail.com